# Conditional Formatting for Paired-Columns

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to set the entire first row as **duplicate-paired dates**
ex: Columns A & B: today's date; Columns C & D: tomorrow's date; Columns E & F:next date and so on until the end of the year.

I used conditional formatting and Autofill with Trend but no luck..
my question is about...how to actually do it without having to manually introduce them.

```
=IF(MOD(COLUMN();2)=0;CELL(A1)+1;CELL(A1))
```

[image: Something like this]

Any advice would help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to populate the date in the first row, in cells `A1` and `B1` use:

```
=TODAY()
```

then, in cell `C1` use:

```
=A1 + 1
```

And populate towards the right for as many columns as you need

Not sure I understand where the conditional formatting comes in...

Comment: You mean `=A1 + 1` in `C1`

Answer (score 0):

## Paired Dates

Today's date is `03/07/2019` which Excel 'translates' to `43531`:

> ```
> =43531+INT(COLUMN()/2)-MOD(COLUMN()-1,2)
> ```

or use any number for the 'starting point'. Format the cells as date of course.

[image]

### Apply to Values

**Rows**

> ```
> =INT(A1/2)-MOD(A1-1,2)+1
> ```

[image]

**Columns**

> ```
> =INT(A1/2)-MOD(A1-1,2)+1
> ```

[image]